# Is there an easier way to split "134h22m54s"?

Tags: javascript, object, split

I'm getting data like "134h22m54s" from an API. With a function I created, it returns as an object includes hours, minutes and seconds.

Here my split function:

```
    parseHMS (value) { // value = "134h22m54s" or "3m0s" or only "0s"
    let hour = "0";
    let minute = "0";
    let second = "0";

    if (value.includes('h')) {
        let splitByHour = value.split('h');
        hour = splitByHour[0]
        value = splitByHour[1];
    }
    if (value.includes('m')) {
        let splitByHour = value.split('m');
        minute = splitByHour[0]
        value = splitByHour[1];
    }
    if (value.includes('s')) {
        let splitByHour = value.split('s');
        minute = splitByHour[0]
    }
    return {h: hour, m: minute, s: second}

}
```

And the output:

```
{
    h: "134", 
    m: "22", 
    s: "54"
}
```

I would like to know if there is an easier way to parse this type of data.

Comment: If your returning time you should be using a standard format, like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Regex could make the 'search' much more easier :)

Comment: If you already have a working code, you can post it on [codereview.se] too (read their help center before asking)

Comment: @Liam the returning value actually is not a time. it is duration. For example; my sleep duration 8 hours 22minutes 14seconds. Hopfully I can explain, my English is not good.

Comment: @LarsFlieger I didn't try regex. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex:

```js
function parseDuration(s) {
    var m = /(?:(\d+)d)?(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m?)?/.exec(s);
    return {
        days: parseInt(m[1], 10) || 0,
        hours: parseInt(m[2], 10) || 0,
        minutes: parseInt(m[3], 10) || 0
    };
}

console.log(parseDuration('10d12h59m'));
console.log(parseDuration('10d12h'));
console.log(parseDuration('10d'));
console.log(parseDuration('12h'));
console.log(parseDuration('70'));
```

Comment: Happy to help :) Regex is really useful sometimes. It's worth learning the basics :D I used this site a lot: https://regex101.com/ (There you can try and error a little bit :D)

Answer (score 2):

As a simple but not *bulletproof* solution you can `split` your *string* by *numeric* characters and `filter` only *numbers*.

```js
const [h,m,s] = "134h22m54s".split(/(\d+)/).filter(Number);
console.log(h,m,s);
```

Comment: For "22m54s" this; it's logging "22 54 undefined". "22" is hours instead of minutes for this situation

Comment: Yeah as I wrote. It is _simple but not bulletproof_. It works only for the pattern which you have provided. For more complex solution please check another answers. They are good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a regular expression here. This can selectively match parts of a string (i.e. it may or may not be there) using non-capturing groups with a quantifier.

```
let parseHMS = (value) => {
  let reg = /(?:(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?)?(\d+)s/
  let result = reg.exec(value)
  return {h: result[1], m: result[2], s: result[3]}
}
```

[Explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/25MMBU/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can improve it, but maybe something like this with regex:

```
const parseHMS = (value) => {
  let reg = /((\d+)h)?((\d+)m)?((\d+)s)/
  let result = reg.exec(value)
  return {h: result[2], m: result[4], s: result[6]}
}
```